# Import doesn't import in r package development

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to create a package. I use the `ggplot2` library for one of the functions.

I have written the import statement for the function:

```
#' @param x the dataframe
#' @param Column the dataframe
#' @param Code the dataframe
#' @keywords Appointment filtering
#' @import ggplot2
#' @importFrom magrittr '%>%'
#' @importFrom dplyr arrange group_by summarise
#' @import rlang
#' @export
```

and written `Imports:ggplot2` in the `DESCRIPTION` as below

```
Package: MyPackage
Title: What the Package Does (one line, title case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("Sebastian", "Zeki", email = "first.last@example.com", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
Depends: R (>= 3.4.0)
Imports:
    ggplot2
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
```

whenever I run `load_all()` or `document()` from the devtools I get the error:

```
Error in ggplot(....) : 
  could not find function "ggplot"
```

I have noticed that the `NAMESPACE` file does not contain ggplot but does have the other imports present but when I add to the `NAMESPACE` manually I get an error saying:

```
Error in importIntoEnv(pkgenv, exports, nsenv, exports) : 
  cannot add bindings to a locked environment
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature in the devel version of `devtools`. 
You need to install it from github from a previous install : `devtools::install_github("hadley/devtools")`

Pkg loading mechanisms have been move to `pkgload`. You can find this feature there. `Pkgload` is loaded by `devtools` so you don't need to bother.

Source for this answer:
It has been asked and answered in [RStudio community forum](https://community.rstudio.com/t/devtools-load-all-doesnt-load-imports-in-the-namespace/1726/3) by a rstudio team member.